# How do I get glyphicons to show up in GridView databind?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

How do I use my `int` `status` field to show correct glyphicons in my `GridView` of `web forms` app?

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <% if (Eval("Status") != null || Eval("Status").ToString() != "0")
        { %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked" />
    <% }
        else
        { %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" />
    <% } %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

> Server Error in '/' Application. Databinding methods such as Eval(),
>   XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound
>   control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ternary operator is the easiest way:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%# Eval("field01") != null || Eval("field01").ToString() != "0" ? "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked\" />" : "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-check\" />" %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Inside a GridView or Repeater etc you have to use a databinding expression `<%# %>`